# Can you explain this to me #ln -s :"target is not a directory"?

Tags: bash, linux

I'm doing this:

```
sudo ln –s /etc/apache2/sites-available/LoginProject /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/LoginProject
```

And I get:

```
ln: target `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/LoginProject' is not a directory
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/LoginProject it's a file

**edit:**

this command:

```
ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/LoginProject /etc/apache2/sites-available/LoginProject
```

outputs:

```
ls: cannot access /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/LoginProject: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 526 2011-09-27 18:40 /etc/apache2/sites-available/LoginProject
```

**edit 2:**

```
$ls /etc/apache2/sites-available/
default  default-ssl  LoginProject
$

$ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
$
```

Comment: Can you add the `ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/LoginProject /etc/apache2/sites-available/LoginProject` output?

Comment: sure, there I added it

Comment: For anyone who arrives here looking for this error, but the above solutions don't work... if you're symlinking a directory, make sure it does NOT have a trailing slash on either the target or the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try: `sudo a2ensite LoginProject`

You could also do `sudo ln –s /etc/apache2/sites-available/LoginProject /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

Comment: The file is: __/etc/apache2/sites-available/LoginProject__ Anyway, I tried changing the order, and didn't worked

Comment: Sorry that was wrong, see edit

Comment: Thanks! the a2ensite LoginProject worked! didn't tried the other command. It's still very weird... I really don't get it

Comment: Normally, ln accepts 2 file paths and if it is more than two, the target must be a directory. I still wonder why it counts your parameters like this way!!!

Answer (score 38):

You probably copied and pasted the `ln -s` command from another source and the system inserted the wrong type of `-`. Try deleting the `-` and typing it again manually.

Comment: You saved my day with this answer! Well, half of the day. I've spent the other half pulling out the remnants of my hair trying to figure out what I was doing wrong and what directory it wants from me. It turned out that I indeed had a wrong dash in the line.

Comment: Great, best answer which should be accepted

Answer (score 8):

The problem is the difference between this...

```
sudo ln –s path1 path2
```

and this...

```
sudo ln -s path1 path2
```

Don't see the difference? *Short dash vs. long dash.*

The long dash is not interpreted as an option and so **ln** sees three paths on the command line and expects the last to be a directory.

Comment: You can actually see the long dash in the original post.  This is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try ***ln*** with single argument like below and see whether it helps,

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ ; sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/LoginProject
```

Answer (score 2):

Try quoting the directories and terminating the `sudo` command arguments like so:

```
sudo -- \ln –s "/etc/apache2/sites-available/LoginProject" "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/LoginProject"
```

Comment: Nope, this didn't make the trick

Comment: Made an edit. Try it again now.

Comment: I copy pasted that and got: __ln: target `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/LoginProject' is not a directory__

Comment: Man. I'm stomped. I've only seen that when the target exists. But your `ls` output shows that it does not. Wondering if it's an SELinux or ACL issue of some kind. Meh, you got it to work with @fuscata's answer. Good job :-)

Comment: Thanks for your time man, @fuscata got a solution, maybe not an answer to why that happend, but still... thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got this, confusingly, when the path of the destination (i.e. the directory to be linked to) had a space in it!

Quoting the path solved the problem.

Comment: you can also add an antislash before the space.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used $PWD. However, when you run the command

`ln -s $PWD/myscript /usr/local/bin/myscript`

then you receive the error message "error: target is not a directory" if your current path contains a space.

The solution is to use quotes:

`ln -s "$PWD/myscript" /usr/local/bin/myscript`